# Many particles in box - physics simulation

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, physics

I'm currently trying to simulate many particles in a box bouncing around.

I've taken into account @kalhartt's suggestions and this is the improved code to initialize the particles inside the box:

```
import numpy as np 
import scipy.spatial.distance as d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# 2D container parameters
# Actual container is 50x50 but chose 49x49 to account for particle radius.
limit_x = 20
limit_y = 20

#Number and radius of particles
number_of_particles = 350
radius = 1

def force_init(n):
    # equivalent to np.array(list(range(number_of_particles)))
    count = np.linspace(0, number_of_particles-1, number_of_particles)
    x = (count + 2) % (limit_x-1) + radius
    y = (count + 2) / (limit_x-1) + radius
    return np.column_stack((x, y))

position = force_init(number_of_particles)
velocity = np.random.randn(number_of_particles, 2)
```

The initialized positions look like this:
[image: The initialized positions look like this]

Once I have the particles initialized I'd like to update them at each time-step. The code for updating follows the previous code immediately and is as follows:

```
# Updating
while np.amax(abs(velocity)) > 0.01:
    # Assume that velocity slowly dying out
    position += velocity
    velocity *= 0.995
    #Get pair-wise distance matrix
    pair_dist = d.cdist(position, position)

    pair_d = pair_dist<=4
    #If pdist [i,j] is <=4 then the particles are too close and so treat as collision
    for i in range(len(pair_d)):
        for j in range(i):
            # Only looking at upper triangular matrix (not inc. diagonal)
            if pair_d[i,j] ==True:
                # If two particles are too close then swap velocities
                # It's a bad hack but it'll work for now.
                vel_1 = velocity[j][:]
                velocity[j] = velocity[i][:]*0.9
                velocity[i] = vel_1*0.9



    # Masks for particles beyond the boundary
    xmax = position[:, 0] > limit_x
    xmin = position[:, 0] < 0
    ymax = position[:, 1] > limit_y
    ymin = position[:, 1] < 0

    # flip velocity and assume that it looses 10% of energy
    velocity[xmax | xmin, 0] *= -0.9
    velocity[ymax | ymin, 1] *= -0.9

    # Force maximum positions of being +/- 2*radius from edge
    position[xmax, 0] = limit_x-2*radius
    position[xmin, 0] = 2*radius
    position[ymax, 0] = limit_y-2*radius
    position[ymin, 0] = 2*radius
```

After updating it and  letting it run to completion I get this result:
[image: coolio result]

This is infinitely better than before but there are still patches that are too close together - such as:
[image: should not be here]

Too close together. I think the updating works... and thanks to @kalhartt my code is wayyyy better and faster (and I learnt some things about numpy... props @kalhartt) but I still don't know where it's screwing up. I've tried changing the order of the actual updates with the pair-wise distance going last or the `position +=velocity` going last but to no avail. I added the *0.9 to make the entire thing die down faster and I tried it with 4 to make sure that 2*radius (=2) wasn't too tight a criteria... but nothing seems to work.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: I just got around to reading through your edit, I've updated my answer with a section on the collisions.

Comment: The final version of the code is available [here](https://gist.github.com/abhinavrk/4d15ccf2facebc660aa3). I've left the bad hack in for the collisions because I don't need great accuracy. If you'd like better code for that I suggest you look at @kalhartt's answer below.

Comment: @Abhinav Ramakrishnan the link is broken. Maybe because your github is private, or because your have moved the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are just two typos standing in your way. First `for i in range(len(positions)/2):` only iterates over half of your particles. This is why half the particles stay in the x bounds (if you watch for large iterations its more clear). Second, the second y condition should be a minimum (I assume) `position[i][1] < 0`. The following block works to bound the particles for me (I didn't test with the collision code so there could be problems there).

```
for i in range(len(position)):
    if position[i][0] > limit_x or position[i][0] < 0:
        velocity[i][0] = -velocity[i][0]
    if position[i][1] > limit_y or position[i][1] < 0:
        velocity[i][1] = -velocity[i][1]
```

As an aside, try to leverage numpy to eliminate loops when possible. It is faster, more efficient, and in my opinion more readable. For example `force_init` would look like this:

```
def force_init(n):
    # equivalent to np.array(list(range(number_of_particles)))
    count = np.linspace(0, number_of_particles-1, number_of_particles)
    x = (count * 2) % limit_x + radius
    y = (count * 2) / limit_x + radius
    return np.column_stack((x, y))
```

And your boundary conditions would look like this:

```
while np.amax(abs(velocity)) > 0.01:
    position += velocity
    velocity *= 0.995

    # Masks for particles beyond the boundary
    xmax = position[:, 0] > limit_x
    xmin = position[:, 0] < 0
    ymax = position[:, 1] > limit_y
    ymin = position[:, 1] < 0

    # flip velocity
    velocity[xmax | xmin, 0] *= -1
    velocity[ymax | ymin, 1] *= -1
```

Final note, it is probably a good idea to hard clip position to the bounding box with something like `position[xmax, 0] = limit_x; position[xmin, 0] = 0`. There may be cases where velocity is small and a particle outside the box will be reflected but not make it inside in the next iteration. So it will just sit outside the box being reflected forever.

**EDIT**: Collision

The collision detection is a much harder problem, but lets see what we can do. Lets take a look at your current implementation.

```
pair_dist = d.cdist(position, position)
pair_d = pair_dist<=4
for i in range(len(pair_d)):
    for j in range(i):
        # Only looking at upper triangular matrix (not inc. diagonal)
        if pair_d[i,j] ==True:
            # If two particles are too close then swap velocities
            # It's a bad hack but it'll work for now.
            vel_1 = velocity[j][:]
            velocity[j] = velocity[i][:]*0.9
            velocity[i] = vel_1*0.9
```

Overall a very good approach, `cdist` will efficiently calculate the distance
between sets of points and you find which points collide with `pair_d = pair_dist<=4`.

The nested for loops are the first problem. We need to iterate over `True` values of `pair_d` where `j > i`. First your code actually iterate over the lower triangular region by using `for j in range(i)` so that `j < i`, not particularly important in this instance as long since i,j pairs are not repeated. However Numpy has two builtins we can use instead, [np.triu](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html) lets us set all values below a diagonal to `0` and [np.nonzero](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) will give us the indices of non-zero elements in a matrix. So this:

```
pair_dist = d.cdist(position, position)
pair_d = pair_dist<=4
for i in range(len(pair_d)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(pair_d)):
        if pair_d[i, j]:
            ...
```

is equivalent to

```
pair_dist = d.cdist(position, position)
pair_d = np.triu(pair_dist<=4, k=1) # k=1 to exclude the diagonal
for i, j in zip(*np.nonzero(pair_d)):
    ...
```

The second problem (as you noted) is that the velocities are just switched and scaled instead of reflected. What we really want to do is negate and scale the component of each particles velocity along the axis that connects them. Note that to do this we will need the vector connecting them `position[j] - position[i]` and the length of the vector connecting them (which we already calculated). So unfortunately part of the `cdist` calculation gets repeated. Lets quit using `cdist` and do it ourselves instead. The goal here is to make two arrays `diff` and `norm` where `diff[i][j]` is a vector pointing from particle i to j (so `diff` is a 3D array) and `norm[i][j]` is the distance between particles i and j. We can do this with numpy like so:

```
nop = number_of_particles

# Give pos a 3rd index so we can use np.repeat below
# equivalent to `pos3d = np.array([ position ])
pos3d = position.reshape(1, nop, 2)

# 3D arras with a repeated index so we can form combinations
# diff_i[i][j] = position[i] (for all j)
# diff_j[i][j] = position[j] (for all i)
diff_i = np.repeat(pos3d, nop, axis=1).reshape(nop, nop, 2)
diff_j = np.repeat(pos3d, nop, axis=0)

# diff[i][j] = vector pointing from position[i] to position[j]
diff = diff_j - diff_i

# norm[i][j] = sqrt( diff[i][j]**2 )
norm = np.linalg.norm(diff, axis=2)

# check for collisions and take the region above the diagonal
collided = np.triu(norm < radius, k=1)

for i, j in zip(*np.nonzero(collided)):
    # unit vector from i to j
    unit = diff[i][j] / norm[i][j]

    # flip velocity
    velocity[i] -= 1.9 * np.dot(unit, velocity[i]) * unit
    velocity[j] -= 1.9 * np.dot(unit, velocity[j]) * unit

    # push particle j to be radius units from i
    # This isn't particularly effective when 3+ points are close together
    position[j] += (radius - norm[i][j]) * unit

...
```

Since this post is long enough already, [here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/kalhartt/9e6f2076cd80f7facfd3) of the code with my modifications.

Comment: Thank you so much. A) for the help with the code... B) for introducing me to some new python functions. I'm tweaking the code presently but its a lot faster. Cheers,